# Inserting data into a temp1 table from a main table where where a record in temp 1 is not in temp2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have created the code below in order to add data to temp table by selecting the top 500 rows from my main table.  a check temp1 does not have a record matching in temp2 but i can seem to get this to work.

```
create table #temp1 (
int_code int,product varchar (10),
vchr_product name varchar (100),
vchr_productgrouplist varchar (max)
vchr_disabledcapabilities varchar (500),
vchr_services varchar (100))

create table #temp2 ( int_code int)

INSERT INTO #temp2

SELECT [int_code]
FROM dbo.tbl_maintable
```

This is where I can't get it right:

```
Insert into #temp1
select top 500 
int_code,
vchr_product name,
vchr_productgrouplist,
vchr_services
from dbo.tbl_maintable 
where #temp2.int_code not in (select int_code form #temp1)
```

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Rather confusing... You don't show where temp1 gets its data. Additionally, you seem to have no way for any data from tbl_maintable to not be in temp2

Comment: should be ,   insert into #temp1  select top 500 
    int_code,
    vchr_product name,
    vchr_productgrouplist,
    vchr_services
from dbo.tbl_maintable 
where #temp2.int_code not in (
    SELECT
        int_code 
    FROM #temp1)

Comment: you should put any edits into the question, not into comments.

Comment: you selected ALL int_code from tbl_maintable and inserted it to #temp2 while you also selected top 500 int_code from same table tbl_maintable and compared it to temp#2 with NOT IN. you will not get any record because ALL int_code are already in #temp2 from tbl_maintable. you have to have at least condition/s on your records to be inserted in temp#2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WHERE clause needs to compare the values in the source table with the values in the #temp2 table. It doesn't really make sense to try and compare values in the destination table (#temp1) because they haven't been inserted yet. So,

```sql
INSERT INTO #temp1 (
    int_code,
    vchr_product name,
    vchr_productgrouplist,
    vchr_services
)
SELECT TOP 500 
    int_code,
    vchr_product name,
    vchr_productgrouplist,
    vchr_services
FROM dbo.tbl_maintable 
WHERE int_code NOT IN (SELECT int_code FROM #temp2)
```

Notice also that you need a column list as part of the INSERT INTO (...) because you don't want `tbl_maintable.vchr_services` values inserted into `#temp1.vchr_disabledcapabilities`.

Comment: Thanks I did have this before but I get a truncated error after 1000 records are inserted but I know there 3000 Records I want the script to run until the temp 1 has all the records in not sure why I am getting the error